# A Messy Cramer's Rule Situation

Tags: determinant, roots-of-unity

Let $\xi_{n}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$. I would like to use cramer's rule to solve:

$\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & \xi_{n} & \xi_{n}^{2} & \cdots & \xi_{n}^{n-1}\\
1 & \xi_{n}^{2} & \xi_{n}^{4} & \cdots & \xi_{n}^{2\left(n-1\right)}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & \xi_{n}^{n-1} & \xi_{n}^{2\left(n-1\right)} & \cdots & \xi_{n}^{\left(n-1\right)^{2}}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
C_{0}\\
C_{1}\\
C_{2}\\
\vdots\\
C_{n-1}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
c_{0}\\
c_{1}\\
c_{2}\\
\vdots\\
c_{n-1}
\end{array}\right)
 $

That is, to find equations for the big Cs in terms of the little cs. But I fear getting lost in the computations. The matrix here is pretty enough that it makes me suspect that someone has done this computation before. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: If m ≤ n, then the matrix V has maximum rank (m) if and only if all αi are distinct. A square Vandermonde matrix is thus invertible if and only if the αi are distinct; an explicit formula for the inverse is known.[2][3][4]  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: My thought too.

Comment: I know about the vandermonde determinant. The question is, how is the formula for the determinant going to be affected when you use cramer's rule to substitute in the constant vector [c_0, c_1,...,c_(n-1)] in the mth column? Having explicit formulae for this would be ideal.